# Native script support for Amazon AWS SNS (push notifications)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, nativescript

I built an app ( which involves push notifications ) in native android code.For push notifications I used Amazon AWS SNS.

I'm trying to build the same app using "Native Script" ,but I'm failed to use AWS SNS in Native Script. It seems there is no support for AWS SNS in "Native script" yet.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already build the app native - maybe you can wrap the notifications in a plugin and reuse it in native script: [NativeScript Plugins](http://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I will try to do as you suggested.If it's possible can you please provide any example.

Comment: Has anyone written an Aws SNS plugin for Nativescript?